# Trouble with Route in laravel collective and laravel 7.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I'm new to laravel. When I try to generate a form, the problem occurred.
My route

```
Route::get('post/add', "Post1Controller@add");
Route::post('post/store', "Post1Controller@store");
```

My Post1Controller

```
 function add()
    {
        return view('post/create');
    }
  function store(Request $request)
    {
        echo "Had file";}
```

My form

```
 {!! Form::open(['url'=> 'post/store','method'=>'POST',  'files'=> true]) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title in here'])!!}

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!form::textarea('content','',['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'Text in here'])!!}

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Add', ['name'=>'sm-add', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger'])!!}

        </div>


        {!! Form::close() !!}`enter code here`
```

My issue: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Open your browser's Developer console, and watch the Network tab. Make sure when you submit the form that it's submitting via POST, and not attempting a redirect, such as HTTP -> HTTPS

Comment: dont open in your browser the URL `http(s)://..../post/store` that will not work, go to the URL `http(s)://..../post/add`

Comment: tks anyway but the problem is still there.

Comment: did you try to check & test it with vanilla code? add <form> as HTML tag and then test :) also i assume you forgot to include csrf ;)

Comment: Did you try `php artisan route:clear` and after that `php artisan optimize`?